# Calling array from the module in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on Visual studio about Python project. I have a module calls `"module1.py"` and main window `"TestForPython.py"`

I create and array and taking input from the user and using in function inside my main. I show you sample basic code (not my code) because of you can understand my question clearly.

```
dynamic_array = []
hexdec = input("Enter the hex number to binary "); 
strArray = [hexdec[idx:idx+2]  for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]
dynamic_array = strArray

def FirstPointer(element):
   print(int(element,16))

FirstPointer(dynamic_array[0])
```

Like I said you this is a basic code.However, my code is more longer and complicated, that's why I want to carry the function to the `"module1"` and call in the main.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You have lists, not arrays.

Comment: First off all thank you for answer  @AndrasDeak, but it doesn't matter, please input `01` and you can see the number.

Comment: Which functionality do you want to use in your other script? Just your ``FirstPointer`` function or also the hex conversion?

Comment: Thank you @DocDriven for answer, actually, I can't separate, because of If I separate it, main function doesn't understand " where is the strArray" that2s why, I want to call everthin just with `FirstPointer(dynamic_array[0])` and taking the input in main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the file you want to import (module1.py):

```
def ConvertHex(hexdec):
    return [hexdec[idx:idx+2]  for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]

def FirstPointer(element):
    print(int(element, 16))
```

In your main file (TestForPython.py), you can utilize these functions like this:

```
import module1

hexdec = input("Enter the hex number to binary ")

dynamic_array = module1.ConvertHex(hexdec)

module1.FirstPointer(dynamic_array[0])
```

Comment: Thank you @DocDriven for your answer but, can I create  `dynamic_array = []` in the `module1.py`and use in  `TestForPython.py`

Comment: Because of I want to use  `dynamic_array[i]` in the `module1.py` because of for loob and It doesn't recognize.

Comment: @Asell: you can, just declare your variables as normal and use them with the new namespace, e.g. ``module1.dynamic_array``.

Comment: Thank you so much @DocDriven

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the same directory to achieve what you want, you only need to import module1 and use it's methods in your main.

If you're working with different directory then it is called package.

check documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Thank you for answer @DarioCruzMinoza I read that documentation before. Howeever when I carry the array to the module1, it doesn't understand, where is the `dynamic array[]`

Comment: did you use a class base module?